# Post to Facebook page with Open Graph

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

trying to figure out why I cannot post to Facebook Page (not profile) with Open Graph API.

I have submitted for review and got approved an action. I have permissions approved, such as:

manage_pages
publish_actions
publish_pages

When I make a post to facebook profile eveything is working fine:

> https://graph.facebook.com/me/com-domain:post?access_token={access_token}&method=POST&property={url}&message=test&fb:explicitly_shared=true

The problem appears to be posting to Facebook Page.

First of all I am making request to /me/accounts and getting proper PAGE ID and Page access token.

> https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token={access_token}

After that, grabing new access token and page id making another request to

> https://graph.facebook.com/{PAGE_ID}/com-domain:post?access_token={page_access_token}&method=POST&property={url}&message=test&fb:explicitly_shared=true

And getting result:

```
{   "error": {
  "message": "Unsupported post request. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
  "type": "GraphMethodException",
  "code": 100,
  "fbtrace_id": "Ffdsfds"   }}
```

Any suggestions ? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

After talking to Facebook support it appears that it is not possible to post via custom actions to Facebook Page. Only to profile. Case closed